# Natural Deduction please help!

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I am sorry for posting this here, but this is my last resort. I have been fighting with these natural deduction problems for the last two weeks. I take an online college logic course and it makes it difficult to get help with problems with no real instructor. Any help would be greatly appreciated, if not I understand. 
The problems are:

$\lnot G  \lor \lnot B$
$G\implies B$
$\therefore \lnot G$

$B \implies F$
$\therefore U \implies (X \implies F)$

$\lnot G \implies (\lnot H \implies \lnot J)$
$\lnot Z \implies (H \implies J)$
$\lnot (G \vee Z)$
$\therefore H=J$

$D=X$

$D \vee X$
$D \implies (\lnot X \vee \lnot Y)$
$\therefore Y$

$(I \implies E) \implies \lnot V$
$(G \implies E) \implies V$
$\therefore \lnot E$

I have some work done on all of them except the last but have hit roadblocks. One of the more difficult things for me to understand is if you have a premise, and you assign a certain letter to P, can you assign that same letter further on in the premise to Q or R?

Any help is much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What does // mean?

Comment: sorry / is the conclusion with the premises above

Comment: Where does each problem start and end? What are you trying to prove in each? Also, what exact work have you done?

Comment: Also, please edit your post to use Mathjax as I have demonstrated with the first piece.

Comment: The // is signifying the conclusion of each problem. There are five problems.I have attempted to work through the problems using various rules of implication and rules of replacement. That is the work I have done but am unable to finish the proof. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

It might help to walk through these in plain English. Take the first one:

$\lnot G  \lor \lnot B$
$G\implies B$
$\therefore \lnot G$

The first line says: Either not G is true or not B is true.

The second line says: If G is true, then B is true as well.

Hence, it cannot be the case that G is true, because if it is, then B is also true. And we have already established in the first line that we must have either not G or not B.

Therefore, the conclusion is: not G.

Edit:

We can also do this more formally. You know $\lnot G  \lor \lnot B$ and you want to show $\lnot G$. So assume each of $\lnot G$ and $\lnot B$ and show that they both imply $\lnot G$. Here we go:

Assume $\lnot G$

$\lnot G \implies \lnot G$

$\therefore \lnot G$

Now assume $\lnot B$

Since $G \implies B, \lnot B \implies \lnot G$  (by the contrapositive)

$\therefore \lnot G$

Hence, it either case, $\lnot G$ is true.

Comment: Here is another way how to do the problem. ¬G∨¬B is equivalent to G ⟹ ¬B which coupled with G ⟹ B gives us G ⟹ B ^ ¬B. G implies a contradiction and the only way how this statement can be true is if G is false.